# How to Add Class to selected element's parent

Tags: jquery, addclass

I want to add class in an element's parent.

The structure of the dom is:

```
<ul class="companies">
<li>
<a id=""></a>
<a id=""></a>
</li>
<li>
<a id=""></a>
<a id=""></a>
</li>
</ul>
```

All the ids of "a" elements are automatic.

I want to add class to the parent "li" of selected "a".

Here is my code:

```
$(".companies li a:selected").parent("li").addClass('selected');
selectDealer($(".companies li a:selected").attr("id"));
```

But when i click one element "a", its parent "li" will not be selected.

Does anyone know why?

Thanks

Comment: What does *selected* mean, when you click on it?

Comment: yes, that's what i mean. I'm not sure my javascript code is right. It's at least an idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I *think* what you're after is a `click` handler here:

```
$(".companies li a").click(function() {
  $(this).parent("li").addClass('selected');
  selectDealer(this.id);
});
```

[`:selected`](http://api.jquery.com/selected-selector/) is for `selected` elements, like `<option>` elements in a `<select>` for example.  If you want something to happen on an event, like `click`, use an event handler like I have above.  Inside the handler, `this` will refer to the element the event's happening on.

The above is for illustration, a more efficient version would use [`.delegate()`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) like this:

```
$(".companies").delegate("li a", "click", function() {
  $(this).parent("li").addClass('selected');
  selectDealer(this.id);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

A link can't be ':selected', this only applies to option elements. Your inital selector is thus failing.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure a:selected can be used like that? Without testing I'd say that's the error